# Why did the EOS token distribution last one year?

Tags: token-distribution, ico, decentralization

What's the rationale behind holding the sale for one year?

Comment: In typical ICOs ,particularly in ETH one who pays high gas tx gets token.Whales would get all if it had for short time. so doing an ico whole year  educate token holder and elimate FUD if you want token to be evenly distrubuted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Block.one's reasoning](https://medium.com/eosio/draft-eos-token-sale-smart-contract-3e10954f2364) for the ICO:

> **1. Equal Opportunity**
>
> In order to ensure that everyone can participate, EOS are not sold for
>   a fixed price; they are sold at a price determined by market demand
>   for their acquisition. This is achieved by distributing a fixed amount
>   of EOS (supply) proportionally toward the daily ETH proceeds (demand).
>
> **2. Broad Awareness**
>
> Distribution can only be as wide as the number of people that are
>   aware of the ability to get involved. By stretching the distribution
>   process out over the course of approximately 1 year, the community has
>   the time to gather information and assess project merits before early
>   stage windows of opportunity are closed.
>
> **3. Fair and Auditable Incoming Value**
>
> An Ethereum smart contract proves the receipt of incoming value for
>   the creation of each EOS token. This process:
>
> - Mimics the economics and distribution access of traditional PoW mining contributions
> - Preserves the value lost to hardware and electricity for PoW
> - Makes it easy for everyone to participate
> - Eliminates unfair advantages associated with economies of scale